# How would you build this component? Flutter Widget Design (Custom Range Slider)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, ui-design

More of  a flexible question, But  I've been looking at this and either don't know enough about flutter (custom drag detectors etc) but the best I have is a range slider (with some sort of overlay that handles the white dots) and then a container that uses math to determine where to clip the vertical bars. However I'm not sure exactly how I'd pull that off

So I'm curious how would you guys pull it off? Custom containers and clips with gesture detectors? Etc. At least from there I'd have an idea as to what method I need to be researching. A starting point as such

Thanks!

Images:

[image: Custom Range Slider]

Comment: there is built in widget for that, is [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RangeSlider-class.html) what you need ?

Comment: @SayyidJ unfortunately not, the range slider doesn't let you customize the overlay (The white dots in the slider handles, thickness of the bar, text underneath the handles) as well as the overlay I need to have the vertical bars that go down in line to the bar itself. 
That's why I'm curious, would others use containers and gesture detectors with state to build out a range slider manually, or would they try some hackery around the existing RangeSlider?